# AJAX returns undefined, failure

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor

I am trying to use the success and failure blocks of the AJAX request. My function is working and I can easily direct to the controller and use my queries to modify my SQL database eg. Everything is working, that was the reason about I didn't notice the AJAX response before.

As I said, I can do my operations without problem but my AJAX always returns failure even that my action is working. I didn't understand the way of fixing it, can you take a look at that please?

**error**

First I tried to log this

```
console.log('Question sending failed:', result.message);
```

Question sending ProductDetail?productId=7:2879
failed: undefined

Then I tried to log this

```
console.log('the entire result: ', result);
```

the entire ProductDetail?productId=7:2880
result:  true

If I log them both at the same time, as a result just this

the entire ProductDetail?productId=7:2880
result:  true

You can see the changes in the codes

**action**

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> SendEmployeeQuestion(SetEmployeeQuestionQuery request)
{
    var result = await MediatrSend(request);
    return Json(result);
}
```

**returns**

[image]

also "true" for "return Json(Result)"

**query**

```
public class SetEmployeeQuestionQuery : IRequest<bool>
    {
        public ClaimModel ClaimModel { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int FirmId { get; set; }
        public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    }

    public class SetEmployeeQuestionQueryHandler : IRequestHandler<SetEmployeeQuestionQuery, bool>
    {
        private readonly IECommerceProductRepository _eCommerceProductRepository;
        public SetEmployeeQuestionQueryHandler(IECommerceProductRepository eCommerceProductRepository)
        {
            _eCommerceProductRepository = eCommerceProductRepository;
        }
        public async Task<bool> Handle(SetEmployeeQuestionQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            string formattedTimestamp = currentDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");

            var questionId = _eCommerceProductRepository.InsertToEmployeeQuestion(request.ClaimModel.EmployeeId, formattedTimestamp).Result;

            await _eCommerceProductRepository.InsertToAnswerLog(null, questionId, request.FirmId, request.QuestionText, null);

            return true;
        }
    }
```

**script**

```
// Ask to seller modal
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.ask-button').on('click', function () {
                $('#askToSellerModal').modal('show');
            });

            $('#askToSellerModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                clearTextarea();
            });

            $('#sendQuestionButton').on('click', function () {
                var productId = "@Model.ProductData.Id";
                var firmId = "@Model.ProductData.FirmId";
                var questionText = $('#askToSellerTextArea').val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("SendEmployeeQuestion")',
                    data: {
                        ProductId: productId,
                        FirmId: firmId,
                        QuestionText: questionText
                    },
                    success: function (result) {
                    if (result.success) {                           
                        console.log('Question sent successfully:', result.message);
                        console.log('the entire result: ', result);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Question sending failed:', result.message);
                        console.log('the entire result: ', result);
                    }
                },
                    error: function (error) {                       
                        console.error('AJAX error:', error.statusText);
                    }
                });

                clearTextarea();
                $('#askToSellerModal').modal('hide');
            });
        });

        function clearTextarea() {
            document.getElementById('askToSellerTextArea').value = '';
        }
```

Comment: You are right, sorry for that. I will edit now

Comment: Can you include your `SetEmployeeQuestionQuery request` class ? I think your problem lies in your data block inside the POST request. Have you tried putting `"ProductId": productId, "FirmId": firmId, "QuestionText": questionText` like this ? Also, instead of success and error blocks, try using `done` and `fail`

Comment: I edit the post with adding SetEmloyeeQuestionQuery. As I said, my query performs well, and I can reach the properties.  I don't think the problem is about attributes

Comment: Thanks for adding the error message, but you've left most of it out. The bit about the async error handler and such was relevant and important. Please copy and paste the **entire** error message into the question.

Comment: Can you `console.log` your entire result, please ?

Comment: I edit the error section. Can you check here please ? I guess I was wrong in the result, it gives me true. But the message is undefined.

Comment: That's possibly because in your `public async Task<bool> Handle`, you are only returning a boolean value of `true` always. You are not passing a message to your response. Thus, you would need to change a bit your async function in order to display a message. Can you log what exactly does your `var questionId` return ? I think I know how we can deal with this. Another question is what does this function do `await _eCommerceProductRepository.InsertToAnswerLog(null, questionId, request.FirmId, request.QuestionText, null);`

Comment: Actually, forget about the aforementioned comment. Can you just put a breakpoint here    `var result = await MediatrSend(request);` and here  `return Json(result);` in your controller ?

Comment: I have two table, my first insertion gives me generated Id for my other table, than I insert the next informations with the questionId it gives my just a normal int which is an Id while creating an entity 

I edit the post, you can see the returns. I can get whatever I want. No problem in here. And as I said SQL working without issue

Comment: you're expecting the JSON you return from the controller to have properties of .success" and ".message".  It's likely that result doesn't have them... so this: if (result.success) is always false.

Comment: I think you may misunderstand the ajax. Ajax.success function is used to do stuff for successful post back and Ajax.error function is used to do stuff if your endpoint get any error or exception. The result in `success: function (result)` is the response data(return Json(result);), your response data is only with value `true` without any parameter named success, so of course in the ajax the result.success will not hit. And your ajax response get the log, that is to say your api successfully post back.

Comment: So if I get it right, do I need to change the return type of the query file from bool to something useful? And maybe the action types themselves? Can you give me an example of providing code, please? It can help me to understand and fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's possibly because in your `async Task<IActionResult> SendEmployeeQuestion`, you are returning a result but you don't set a status and a message so you can handle it afterwards on your AJAX response. You are not passing a message to your response. Thus, you would need to change a bit your function to be able to use to this manner.

I have put a `try catch` exception block to your `HttpPost` function so you can handle the errors when the request fails. That means that it will enter inside the error block of your AJAX.

As you didn't mention what does your `MediatrSend` function does, I assumed that it sends a back an `HttpStatusCode`.

```
     public class BaseResponse
    {
       public bool status { get; set; }
       public string message { get; set; }
   }


     [HttpPost]
     [Authorize]
     public async Task<IActionResult> SendEmployeeQuestion(SetEmployeeQuestionQuery request)
     {

       BaseResponse resp = new BaseResponse();
       try {
            var resultContent = await MediatrSend(request);
            var jsonResponse = resultContent.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            if (result.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                resp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BaseResponse>(jsonResponse.Result);
                resp.status = true;
                resp.message = "Success message.";
            }
            else
            {
                resp = new BaseResponse();
                resp.status = false;
                resp.message = "error message";
            }
       } catch (Exception ex) {
            resp = new BaseResponse();
             resp.status = false;
            resp.message = $"error in response {Ex.Message}"; 
        }
      
       return resp;
    }
```

Therefore, your AJAX code should be written like this:

```
              $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("SendEmployeeQuestion")',
                data: {
                    ProductId: productId,
                    FirmId: firmId,
                    QuestionText: questionText
                },
                success: function (result) {
                  if (result.status === true) {                           
                    console.log('Question sent successfully:', result.message);
                    console.log('the entire result: ', result);
                   } else {
                    console.log('Question sending failed:', result.message);
                    console.log('the entire result: ', result);
                   }
                },
                error: function (error) {                       
                    console.error('AJAX error:', error.message);
                }
            });
```

I hope that my example can more or less guide you to find a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort. I modified my code based on your answer. It looks like working for now!

Comment: I mean, it makes sense that it works. You can surely optimize it a bit. The basic logic for returning a status and a message through your Ajax request would be that.

Comment: Yes, I optimized it for my use-case.